# RSA Crypto reconstructing m by knowing (m mod p)

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Let $c = m^e \mod N$ be a RSA-ciphertext with $N = pq$.

Let
$m_p = m \mod p$ be known

Knowing this, how can i reconstruct $m$ in polynomial time with respect to $log N$ and $log e$ ?

I suspect it might have to do with chinese remainder theorem, but i am not entirely sure. I know we need to find m, such that

$gcd(m - m_p, N) = p$, but i dont quite see, how we can do that in polynomial time

Comment: It's the right idea to look for something whose gcd with N is p, but the whole point is that you don't know m and want to find it, so the gcd you wrote down is not helpful. You've got this thing $m_p$, try to make use of that.

Comment: This has not brought me further unfortunately. Do you maybe have another hint?

Comment: Instead of $m-m_p$, which you don't know, try using $c-c_p$, where you know $c$ and you can calculate $c_p$ from $m_p$ and the public key $e$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have thought about that too, but came to the conclusion that this is not possible, because p is not known and we can not calculate $m_p^e \mod p$ as a result

Comment: Plug it in as $m$ and solve for $c \bmod p$

Comment: @Fluctuation10111 Yes, you're right about that. Still, you can calculate $m_p^e \bmod N$ (instead of $\bmod p$) which works just as well. You will still have two known numbers that differ by some multiple of $p$.